# Wordpress site gives me 301 error with page code under it. Page works when refreshing

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am having so much trouble with getting there mod rewrites to work. I have a site on the server that is in a subfolder called /site2013/

When you go to any page on the site it loads but when you click on any link you get a white page with the page HTML on it. Here is the site: http://willowtreespaoh.com

Once there click something under services and you will see the error.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: The site does not exhibit the issue you describe, are you sure this is not a spam disguised as a question?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to wp-admin, visit permalinks, then click "Save". It will update all the permalinks.

FYI: I'm able to visit pages, so perhaps you've having a caching issue.